# map2() function gives <dbl [1]> as the output. Looking for a real value

Tags: r, purrr

Initializing arrays and functions:

```
MSFE_mine <- function(a0,a1) {
  yhat <- a0+a1*5
  dev <- (5 - yhat)^2
  return((mean(dev, na.rm=TRUE)))
}

a0 <- seq(500,2500,by=100)
a1 <- seq(-100,100,by=10)
```

Merge two array sequences in data.frame:

```
data.frame(a0,a1) %>%
  mutate(map=map2(a0,a1,MSFE_mine))

a0   a1  map
500 -100 <dbl [1]>      
600 -90 <dbl [1]>       
700 -80 <dbl [1]>       
800 -70 <dbl [1]>       
900 -60 <dbl [1]>       
1000 -50 <dbl [1]>      
1100 -40 <dbl [1]>      
1200 -30 <dbl [1]>      
1300 -20 <dbl [1]>      
1400 -10 <dbl [1]>
```

I am getting `<dbl [1]>` as the output for all rows in the map column. How can I make it a integer value?

If I try this:

```
MSFE_mine(500,-100)
> 25
```

It gives me a valid number like I want for the data.frame

Comment: `data.frame(a0,a1) %>%
  mutate(map=map2(a0,a1,MSFE_mine))` works for me. However, you could try `map2_dbl` instead.

Comment: It works for me too.

Comment: The output you have isn't "invalid"—`map` and `map2` generally return lists. You got a column that's a list of vectors. However, I and others aren't getting a list-column. I'm using `purrr` 0.3.1. Maybe something in this behavior changed?